# Type error: 'Post' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Post'?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I made a blog app with Nextjs + Sanity but I'm having an error on my [slug].tsx

I'm getting the error:

> Type error: 'Post' refers to a value, but is being used as a type
> here. Did you mean 'typeof Post'?

The file has the .tsx extension and Post interface is declared on a typings.d.ts file. I read on other solutions that I should make sure that .tsx is the extension instead of .ts but does that refer also to the typings file? Because I tried to change the .ts file into .tsx but it doesn't get solved.

If I change the Post to *typeof Post* error disappears but then a lot of warning appears when calling properties of Post.

**[slug].tsx file**

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import { sanityClient, urlFor } from '../../sanity'
import PortableText from 'react-portable-text'
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form'

interface IFormInput {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  comment: string;
}

interface Props {
    post: Post; 
}

export default function Post({ post }: Props) {

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

    console.log(post);
    

  const { 
    register,
    handleSubmit, 
    formState: { errors } 
  } = useForm<IFormInput>()

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
    fetch('/api/createComment', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(data);
      setSubmitted(true);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      setSubmitted(false);
    })
  };

  return (
    <main>
        <Header />

        <img 
          className='w-full h-40 object-cover' 
          src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()!} 
          alt="" />

          <article className='max-w-3xl mx-auto p-5'>
            <h1 className='text-3xl mt-10 mb-3 font-extrabold text-[#292929] '>{post.title}</h1>
            <h2 className='text-xl font-light text-gray-500 mb-2'>{post.description}</h2>

            <div className='flex items-center space-x-2'>
              <img className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full' src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()!} alt="" />
              <p className='font-extralight text-sm'>
                Blog post by <span className='text-green-600'>{post.author.name}</span> - Published at {new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleString()}
              </p>
            </div>

            <div className='mt-10'>
              <PortableText 
                className=''
                dataset={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET!}
                projectId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID!}
                content={post.body}
                serializers={{ 
                  h1: (props: any) => (
                    <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold my-5' {...props} />
                  ),
                  h2: (props: any) => (
                    <h2 className='text-xl font-bold my-5' {...props} />
                  ),
                  li: ({ children }: any) => (
                    <li className='ml-4 list-disc'>{children}</li>
                  ),
                  link: ({ href, children }: any) => (
                    <a href={href} className='text-blue-500 hover:underline'>
                      {children}
                    </a>
                  ),
                 }}
              />
            
            </div>

          </article>

          <hr className='max-w-lg my-5 mx-auto border border-yellow-500' />

          {submitted ? (
              <div className='flex flex-col p-10 my-10 bg-yellow-500 text-white max-w-2xl mx-auto'>
                <h3 className='text-3xl font-bold'>
                  Thank you for submitting your comment!
                </h3>
                <p>Once it has been approved, it will appear below!</p>
              </div>
          ): (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='flex flex-col p-5 max-w-2xl mx-auto mb-10' action="">
            <h3 className='text-sm text-yellow-500'>Enjoyed this article?</h3>
            <h4 className='text-3xl font-extrabold text-[#292929]'>Leave a comment below!</h4>
            <hr className='py-3 mt-2' />

            <input
                {...register("_id")}
                type="hidden"
                name="_id"
                value={post._id}
              />

            <label className='block mb-5'>
              <span className='text-gray-700'>Name</span>
              <input {...register("name", {required: true})} 
              className='shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 form-input mt-1 block w-full ring-yellow-500 focus:ring-1 focus:outline-none' type="text" name="name" placeholder='John Appleseed' />
            </label>
            <label className='block mb-5'>
              <span className='text-gray-700'>Email</span>
              <input {...register("email", {required: true})} 
              className='shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 form-input mt-1 block w-full ring-yellow-500 focus:ring-1 focus:outline-none' placeholder='John Appleseed' type="text" />
            </label>
            <label className='block mb-5'>
              <span className='text-gray-700'>Comment</span>
              <textarea {...register("comment", {required: true})}
              className='shadow border rounded py-2 px-3 mt-1 block w-full ring-yellow-500 focus:ring-1 focus:outline-none' placeholder='John Appleseed' rows={8} />
            </label>

            {/* errors will return when field validation fails */}

            <div className='flex flex-col p-5'>
              {errors.name && (<span className='text-red-500'>- The Name field is required</span>)}
              {errors.comment && (<span className='text-red-500'>- The Comment field is required</span>)}
              {errors.email && (<span className='text-red-500'>- The Email field is required</span>)}
            </div>

            <input className='shadow bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-400 transition-colors focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer' type="submit"  />
          </form>
          )}

          {/* Comments */}
          <div className='flex flex-col p-10 my-10 max-w-2xl mx-auto shadow-yellow-500 shadow space-y-2'>
            <h3 className='text-4xl font-extrabold text-[#292929]'>Comments</h3>
            <hr className='pb-2' />

            {post.comments.map((comment) => (
              <div key={comment._id}>
                <p><span className='text-yellow-500'>{comment.name}: </span>{comment.comment}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          
    </main>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const query = `*[_type == "post"]{
        _id,
        slug {
          current
        }
      }`;

      const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

      const paths = posts.map((post: Post) => ({
        params: {
            slug: post.slug.current,
        },
      }));

      return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking',
      };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({params}) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
      _id,
      _createdAt,
      title,
      author-> {
        name,
        image
      },
        'comments': *[
          _type == "comment" &&
          post._ref == ^._id &&
          approved == true],
      description,
      mainImage,
      slug,
      body
    }`

      const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query, {
        slug: params?.slug,
      });

      if (!post) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
      }

      return {
        props: {
            post,
        },
        revalidate: 60, // after 60s it will update the old cached version
      }
}
```

**typings.d.ts file**

```
export interface Post {
    _id: string;
    _createdAt: string;
    title: string;
    author: {
        name: string;
        image: string;
    };
    comments: Comment[];
    description: string;
    mainImage: {
        asset: {
            url: string;
        };
    };
    slug: {
        current: string;
    };
    body: [object];
}

export interface Comment {
    approved: boolean;
    comment: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    post: {
        _ref: string;
        _type: string;
    };
    _createdAt: string;
    _id: string;
    _rev: string;
    _type: string;
    _updatedAt: string;
}
```

Comment: I think what is happening here is that your `Post` component, which is essentially just a function, is getting hoisted, and your `Props` interface is actually using the component function instead of the type. Perhaps you should change the name of your component, or the type

Answer (score 1):

You have `interface Post` and `function Post()`. I'm assuming you want the former in `interface Props`, but the compiler, and the JS engine, infers the latter.

Rename one of them, naming different things with the same name is rarely a good idea anyway.

Comment: This happens because of hoisting - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting